# Which is best DPAPI or HSM?

Tags: password-management, key-management, pci-dss

Can you please explain what's is the main difference between for this both DPAPI and 
 HSM? As far as I understand both protecting the data, the way of protection is difference HSM is physical device and DPAPI provide operating system-level data protection.
   Which is the best method/way to protect the Cardholder data according to the PCI-DSS standards?

Thanks,
Chandru

Comment: DPAPI is what you do when you do not have a HSM and you still want to make believe that you have actual security against local attackers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PCI DSS 3.5.2**

> Store secret and private keys used to encrypt/decrypt cardholder data
>   in one (or more) of the following forms at all times:
>
> - Encrypted with a key-encrypting key that is at least as strong as the    data-encrypting key, and that is stored separately from the
>     data-encrypting key
> - Within a secure cryptographic device (such as a host security module    (HSM) or PTS-approved point-of-interaction device)
> - As at least two full-length key components or key shares, in    accordance with an industry-accepted method

It depends. DPAPI is just an API that provides a simple  cryptographic application programming interface. Meaning it allows you to safely use cryptographic functions without you having to worry how they work. The DPAPI allows for automatic key expiration (which is one of the PCI-DSS rules).

The benefit of an HSM is that it's a hardware module which can be made tamper proof. Often they are also certified for key storage (FIPS compliance). Performance wise it *can* be more effective.

Personally I would consider an HSM if you've got the budget. According to PCI-DSS there is actually no best, either are good providing your implementation is done correctly.

Comment: Thanks Lucas..Are you preferred any HSM device?